# Fixed point method- show a fixed pt

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

One of my HW questions is consider the equation $x^2+cos(x)-10x=0$ for some x in 0,1 closed. Show that a solution of this equation is a fixed point of $g(x)=\frac{x^2+cos(x)}{10}$. I’m not sure how to start this question because I don’t understand how to use knowing that we have a root to show a fixed point. I would appreciate a small push in the right direction so I can figure out how to start this question!

Comment: Use algebra to convert the given equation to $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Oh that makes a ton of sense thank you!